# Connecting my definition of $f \pitchfork Z$ with

Tags: differential-geometry, definition

I am reading the Transversality Theorem and I had to remind myself what the strange definitions mean.

For manifolds,

> Let $X,Y \subset Z$ be sub manifolds and $x \in X \cap Y$, then $X \pitchfork Y $ means their tangent space $T_x X + T_x Y = T_x Z$

For maps

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a smooth map and $Z \subset Y$ be a sub manifold. Then $f$ is traverse to $Z$ if $$Im(df_x) + T_{f(x)}Z = T_{f(x)}Y$$

So here is what my definition of what I thought $f \pitchfork Z$ would mean. If given a smooth map $f: X \to Y$ and sub manifold $Z \subset Y$. Then to suggest a definition for $f \pitchfork Z$, one would consider

Let $a \in f(X) \cap Z$ (so there is an assumption that $f(X) \subset Y$ is already a sub manifold), then $f(X) \pitchfork Z$ means $$T_af(X) + T_aZ = T_aY$$

Let $\phi: U \to R^{\dim f(X)}$ be a local parametrization where $U\subset R^k$, then we define $$T_af(X) = Im(\{d\phi_0 : d\phi_0 : R^k \to R^{\dim f(X)} \}).$$ Now I am almost certain what am I writing is the same because there is an isormophism $T_x(X) \approx R^k$, so $df_x$ and $d\phi_0$ must be the same up to diffeomorphism is what I am suspecting. But I am not sure. I am guessing transversality between maps and sub manifolds gives more freedom of thought in geometry?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but if $X,Y\subset Z$ are submanifolds, you can consider the (smooth) inclusion $i:X\to Z$. Then, the derivative of $i$ at $x\in X$ satisfies $d_xi(T_x Z) = T_{x}X$, and the condition that the map $i$ is transversal to $Y$ is exactly $T_{x}X+T_{x}Y=T_{x}Z$, and you recover the definition of transversality for submanifolds.

Comment: @ViníciusNovelli No I am considering the situation in my question.